# SvelteKit not exporting enviornment variables on npm build

Tags: environment-variables, vite, sveltekit

I'm trying to build my SvelteKit project on an `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` server. When I run `npm run build` Everything compiles besides at the end when I get an error from SvelteKit/Vite about my enviornment variables not being exported, but being imported. Here's the output:

```
"PUBLIC_API_URL" is not exported by "$env/static/public", imported by "src/components/poweraction/PowerButton.svelte".
file: /home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/src/components/poweraction/PowerButton.svelte:2:11
1: <script>
2:   import { PUBLIC_API_URL } from '$env/static/public'
              ^
3:   import { logUpdate } from "../../Stores.js";
4:   export let action;
error during build:
RollupError: "PUBLIC_API_URL" is not exported by "$env/static/public", imported by "src/components/poweraction/PowerButton.svelte".
    at error (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2125:30)
    at Module.error (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13423:16)
    at Module.traceVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13830:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12389:39)
    at ReturnValueScope.findVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:6974:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:6974:38)
    at ReturnValueScope.findVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:6974:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:6974:38)
    at Identifier.bind (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:8124:40)
    at BinaryExpression.bind (file:///home/ubuntu/Tia/panel/front/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:5747:23)
```

I've tried rebuilding, and looking on other forums. I was hoping for it to Build properly but I cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: Is the variable provided during build? If it is only available upon running the application you should use `$env/dynamic/public`.

Comment: Hi @H.B. I'm still getting that same error. `"PUBLIC_API_URL" is not exported by "$env/dynamic/public", imported by "src/components/poweraction/PowerButton.svelte".` Is it something to do with my .env being in my project root? Should it go in src?

Comment: Whether `.env` does anything depends on the adapter. See respective docs, e.g. when using Node they [need to be loaded explicitly](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables). The location should be correct.